# What is the difference between Solution-Verification and Challenge-Response variants of Proof of Work;

Tags: terminology, cryptocurrency, proof-of-work

Sorry if question is really dumb, I am new to crypto :(

If the client provides the solution for the PoW Challenge-Response, in my understanding, the solution of that challenge should be verified. So I don't understand, if the verification process is involved in Challenge-Response, what's the difference between them?

If it's possible, can someone send implementation of Challenge Response variant. I've been searching for it for 1 week, but the only thing I can find is Solution-Verification one.